# S22.IMAP causing exceptions while "idling"

Tags: vb.net, imap

I am trying to use the S22.Imap library (https://github.com/smiley22/S22.Imap) to listen for new messages.
I have followed the examples provided, but am in need of help...
According to what I have read, the ImapClient object should sit in the background and listen for new messages (using the IDLE feature) and raise an event when a new message is received.
And it seems to work... for a while!
I am using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.
I have a simple VB.NET Windows Forms project - here is the code:

```
Imports S22.Imap

Public Class Form1

    Private Shared Sub UnhExceptionHandler(sender As Object, e As System.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
        Console.WriteLine("Unhandled UI Exception: {0}", DirectCast(e.ExceptionObject, Exception).Message)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub ThrExceptionHandler(sender As Object, e As System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs)
        Console.WriteLine("Unhandled Thread Exception: {0}", e.Exception.Message)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf UnhExceptionHandler
        AddHandler System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException, AddressOf ThrExceptionHandler
         Try
            Dim c As ImapClient = New ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", 993, "john@john-online.co.uk", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", AuthMethod.Login, True)
            ' Should ensure IDLE is actually supported by the server
            If c.Supports("IDLE") = False Then
                Console.WriteLine("Server does not support IMAP IDLE")
            Else
                ' We want to be informed when new messages arrive
                AddHandler c.NewMessage, New EventHandler(Of IdleMessageEventArgs)(AddressOf OnNewMessage)

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub OnNewMessage(sender As Object, e As IdleMessageEventArgs)
        Console.WriteLine("A new message arrived. Message has UID: " & Convert.ToString(e.MessageUID))
    End Sub

End Class
```

When I run this, all goes well for a while - I receive new message notifications OK, but after a while, if I disconnect and reconnect my network connection, I get the following message in 'UnhExceptionHandler()':

```
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
```

In this code example, I could simply trap the error and restart the ImapCLient connection. But this is just to test the S22.Imap library - I want to use it in an application where many accounts are checked simultaneously, so need I need to be able to trap the error and determine which individual ImapClient object raised it?

Can anyone suggest any possible resolutions?

Comment: Does not 'sender' include which object threw the exception?

Comment: In this scenario, 'sender' is System.AppDomain. I can determine that the error was raised in the S22.Imap library from System.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs, but I can't see a way of telling which particular instance of the ImapClient object raised the error, if multiple instances are active.

Comment: Could you add a full Stacktrace `Exception.ToString()`
This is currently a somewhat known issue in S22.Imap, I have a solution but I would like to make it more generic before i provide it as a answer.